# How to avoid clustered index scan whilst querying on aggregated count of subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to optimise this query so that it avoids a clustered index scan of both the RecipeIngredient & RecipeInstruction tables.

I also need to able to page through the results so it needs to return 20 every time.

The only way I have been able to avoid the clustered index scan so far is to select a larger set and pick the top 20 however I'm sure there must be a better and more reliable way.

The most recent recipes are always changing and so caching is not an option

```
select top 20
    Recipe.RecipeID,
    Ingredients.IngredientCount
    Instructions.InstructionCount

from Recipe

left join (
    select RecipeID,
    Count(RecipeIngredientID) as IngredientCount
    from RecipeIngredient
    group by RecipeID
) 
as Ingredients on Recipe.RecipeID = Ingredients.RecipeID

left join (
    select RecipeID,
    Count(RecipeInstructionID) as InstructionCount
    from RecipeInstruction
    group by RecipeID
) 
as Instructions on Recipe.RecipeID = Instructions.RecipeID


where 
IngredientCount > 4
and
IngredientCount = InstructionCount

order by Recipe.RecipeID desc
```

Comment: You can start by removing the `LEFT JOIN`s.  They are turned into inner joins anyway.

Comment: It looks like you don't need to involve table `Recipe` at all, you should filter using a `having` critera.

Comment: _most recent recipes are always changing_ There is nothing in your query to support that as far as I can tell, nor is there any obvious column that can be used to determine that. Let's ignore that since it is not related to performance at this point. Somehow you have determined that clustered index scans are bad. Start by [posting the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and the DDL of the tables involved. Guessing, especially at a distance, is not particularly effective.

Answer (score 0):

seems like this can be simplified to this:

```
select top 20 
      RecipeID
      , Count(distinct RecipeInstructionID) as InstructionCount
      , Count(distinct RecipeIngredientID) as IngredientCount
from RecipeIngredient ri
join RecipeInstruction rs
      on ri.RecipeID = rs.RecipeID
group by RecipeID
having 
      InstructionCount > 4 
      and IngredientCount = InstructionCount
```

Comment: looks good. As in this example, learn how "having" instead of "where" is applied after grouping, which is what you're asking for.